# Struts2 datetimepicker not showing

Tags: java, jsp, dojo, struts2, datetimepicker

I followed [THIS](http://www.roseindia.net/struts/struts2/date/struts-2-datetimepicker.shtml) but had no luck.

My .*jsp* file has in ***head*** tag:

```
<s:head theme="ajax" />
```

and in ***body*** tag

```
<s:datetimepicker name="dateOfBirth" label="Format (yyyy-MM-dd)" displayFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
```

But it is not showing, here is the picture:

[image: picture]

My generated HTML source code contains all necessary lines like in [example](http://www.roseindia.net/struts/struts2/date/struts-2-datetimepicker.shtml) (***script*** tags and other are generated....)

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Following Quaternion's answer:

I was using, ***struts2-core-2.0.12.jar*** which recognized `<s:datetimepicker />` tag but wasn't showing in my *jsp* page. After replacing ***struts2-core-2.0.12*** with newer one ***struts2-core-2.2.1.jar***, `<s:datetimepicker />` tag wasn't recognized.

After putting `<%@ taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags" %>` in head of the file it wasn't recognized as my tag library. Based on [THIS](http://old.nabble.com/DoJo-Plugin-for-struts-2.0.11-td19062990.html), you should download ***struts2-dojo-plugin-2.1.2.jar*** separately and add it into your ***WEB-INF/lib*** folder (you can downlad it [here](http://people.apache.org/builds/struts/2.1.2/) --> **struts-2.1.2-lib.zip** --> **struts2-dojo-plugin-2.1.2.jar**).

After that you just use **sx** tag for your datetimepicker.

**IMPORTANT**: Don't forger to put `<sx:head/>` in head tag of your *jsp* page --> examples [here](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/docs/dojo-head.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The later versions of struts2 require:
<%@ taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags" %>

Then of course change the tag namespace, using:

```
<sx:datetimepicker name="dateOfBirth" label="Format (yyyy-MM-dd)" displayFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
```

See [Struts2 datetimepicker](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/docs/datetimepicker.html) It's best if you consult struts.apache.org and ensure you are using the documentation at the correct version, things change!

Answer (score 1):

use 
sx:head  tag in the head section of jsp.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %> included? I miss that at times wondering why things do not show up.